# Rails 4.1 upgrade, having trouble with group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So my 3.2 code looks like this

```
AssocGenre.includes(:genre).where(attachable_type: Project).count(group:   'genres.name').sort_by{|k,v| -v}.each do
```

But now it's giving me this error

```
undefined method `sort_by' for 193:Fixnum
```

What is the correct syntax for this in rails 4.1 now?

Comment: what are you trying to sort/count?

Comment: Are there 193 matches to your query by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used to be able to specify the GROUP BY clause when calling `count` but not anymore. Now you have to specify the GROUP BY with a separate `group` call. From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count):

> **count**(column_name = nil, options = {})
>
> Count the records.
>   [...]
>   If `count` is used with `group`, it returns a Hash whose keys represent the aggregated column, and the values are the respective amounts:
>
> ```
> Person.group(:city).count
> # => { 'Rome' => 5, 'Paris' => 3 }
> ```

You probably want to include a simple INNER JOIN in the SQL rather than all the extra stuff that [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) adds so [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) should work better.

So you want to write it this way now:

```
AssocGenre.joins(:genre)
          .where(attachable_type: Project)
          .group('genres.name')
          .count
          .sort_by ...
```

Comment: Worked great, but I had to change includes to joins.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `includes` at all.

Answer (score 1):

just have a try :

```
AssocGenre.includes(:genre).where(attachable_type: Project).count(group:'genres.name').**to_a**.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.each.....
```

Comment: This won't work, `count` doesn't take a `:group` option for supplying a GROUP BY clause in Rails4.